# Can't open eshell in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, eshell

I am new to emacs/spacemacs and I saw some really cool videos and read through some articles and I really want to get it working.

when I hit SPC + ' it says "SPC ' is undefined" Anyone know how to fix this or what the problem might be?

according to the documentation this is supposed to open an eshell window. (I am using MacOS). If I hit just SPC to see what is bound there is no SPC ' bind.

I have read through so many articles trying to figure this out. https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Btools/shell

Am I missing something? I wish there was a spacemacs wiki! I would go and use full emacs and try to get it to a point where maybe it is similar to spacemacs... but I am so new to this I thought something fully packaged was best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need install shell layer first, see install section of shell layer.

Or you can run eshell function directly, "SPC : eshell RET" or "M-x eshell RET".

Comment: Thank you! After taking a slow look through the .spacemacs file I found it is actually commented out by default. Thank you!!